# Inkscape without the GUI

Tags: inkscape

I am running a batch script to convert SVG files to PDF files.

```
INDIR='...'
OUTDIR='...'

seq 1 1000 | while read row; do
  echo Processing $row
  /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape -o $OUTDIR/$row.pdf --without-gui $INDIR/$row.svg 
done
```

And because I have 4 cores, I'm running 4 of these batches at the same time.

But the `--without-gui` option is still opening the application on the Dock. This prevents me from seeing my desktop and is probably unnecessarily slowing down processing. Can this actually be disabled?

[image]

Comment: Maybe inkscape shell would be better suited? https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line#Shell_mode

Comment: --batch-process is not available yet in a released version. Check the man page for your version. The --shell mode might be useful, indeed.

Comment: This is an OS issue, not a design question.

Comment: @Moini that's it, thank you!